# Sinatra/Rack session.fetch producing unexpected results

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I was writing a quick helper in Sinatra for `redirect_to_next`, where I redirect to the path provided by `session[:next]` if it exists, or a default.

In Sinatra, `session` really provided by Rack, and by [spec](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html), it is said to provide a hash like interface for [`fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch). I wrote the following error helper to explain my problem.

```
error 401 do
  session[:next] = request.path
  puts "get   #{session[:next]}"
  puts "fetch #{session.fetch(:next, '/')}"
  redirect "/login"
end
```

When I attempt to access */settings* when not logged in, I `halt 401` which runs the above code. This is what it prints to my terminal:

```
get   /settings
fetch /
```

`:next` exists as a key, so why is it giving me the default as if it does not?

**Update**

This minimal example shows the same behavior.

```
require 'sinatra'

set :sessions, true

get '/' do
  session[:testing] = "hello"
  puts "get   #{session[:testing]}"
  puts "fetch #{session.fetch(:testing, 'goodbye')}"
end
```

Logs

```
[2012-04-29 14:11:51] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1954 port=9292
get   hello
fetch goodbye
10.0.2.2 - - [29/Apr/2012 14:11:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0485
```

Software

- ruby (1.9.3p194)
- rack (1.4.1)
- sinatra (1.3.2)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here. Is it possible for you to provide a minimal but complete example that displays this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session hash isn’t a normal Ruby `Hash`, it’s a [`Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L50). `SessionHash` actually inherits from `Hash`, but it [overrides the `[]=`  and `[]` methods, calling `to_s` on any keys before storing and retrieving them](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L70-L73).

Extending your update example:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :sessions, true

get '/' do
  session[:testing] = "hello"
  puts "get               #{session[:testing]}"
  puts "fetch             #{session.fetch(:testing, 'goodbye')}"
  puts "fetch with string #{session.fetch(:testing.to_s, 'goodbye')}"
end
```

gives this output:

```
get               hello
fetch             goodbye
fetch with string hello
```

When you use [`Hash#fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch), passing a symbol, the method gets dispatched directly to the parent hash, without being converted to a string, and so the matching key isn’t found.

So, always use Strings as keys in your sessions and everything should work.